# routeLink not working with Angular Material MdTableModule/CdkTableModule md-cell

Tags: angular, angular-material2

According to Angular Material [official documents](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview), 
MdTable was built on the top of [CdkTable](https://material.angular.io/guide/cdk-table).

If put a `routeLink` attribute of  an `a` element inside of a `md-cell` element with a **expression**, such as

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="name">
  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Name</md-header-cell>
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" >
    <a routerLink="/customers/{{row.id}}">{{row.name}}</a>
  </md-cell>
</ng-container>
```

the error stack in the console:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):TypeError:renderer.setAttribute is not a function
TypeError: renderer.setAttribute is not a function
at MdTable.CdkTable (cdk.es5.js:1869)
at new MdTable (material.es5.js:20855)
at createClass (core.es5.js:10924)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10742)
at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12178)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12624)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12533)
at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12205)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12624)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12533)
at MdTable.CdkTable (cdk.es5.js:1869)
at new MdTable (material.es5.js:20855)
at createClass (core.es5.js:10924)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10742)
at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12178)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12624)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12533)
at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12205)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12624)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12533)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:784)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:755)
at zone.js:832
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.682.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.682.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Zone.webpackJsonp.682.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:596)
at <anonymous>
```

The root cause of the problem is `{{row.id}}` in the value of `routerLink` .

When I change the `a` element as follow, the exception will disappear.

`<a (click)="navigate(row)">{{row.name}}</a>`

`navigate` is a customized function defined in the `component`.

Comment: post the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with the MdTable and would occur anywhere you tried to use routerLink like that. You're not binding to `row.id` but rather passing the string `"/customers/{{row.id}}"` as the destination, which routerLink seems to be tripping up on.

Instead try this,

```
<a [routerLink]="['/customers', row.id]">{{row.name}}</a>
```